# "Whole Wide World" , "Whole World" , "World" Any Difference?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

> Traveling the world.
>
> Traveling the whole world.
>
> Traveling the whole wide word.

Is there any difference between these or is it just dressing up?

Answer (score 2):

> Traveling the world.
>
> Traveling the whole world.
>
> Traveling the whole wide word.

"Is there any difference between these or is it just dressing up?"

ANSWER: You are correct. The accompanying phrases are basically "dressing up" the first statement. "Traveling the whole world" implies having visited every country, which in practical terms is impossible, while "Traveling the whole wide world" suggests the person is simply very well traveled internationally.

"Traveling the world" is quite a claim in itself, but it is more modest and realistic than the other two statements.